# Selenium PhantomJS Scrolling Down

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, phantomjs

I tried to scrolling down with selenium, But i use webdriver PhantomJS. I tried selenium for test javascript instagram. As you know, on instagram there have button "Load More", after click button "Load More", we don't have to click again becouse it will auto refresh and it will show more image.

I tried like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='_8ioip _glw1t']").click()
time.sleep(5)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(3.6)
```

Actually this code it's work, but not really work, i mean something weird happening at the "time.sleep". If i give 2, the result  are few and if i give 3 the result are just pretty much, But if i give 5, the result same like i give 2.

The question is, How to make teh Scroll get all data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class of "Load more" button seems to have changed.
your code is correct, try with this xpath:

```
//a[@class='_8imhp _glz1g']
```

or try to locate the button by it's text content:

```
//*/div/a[text()[contains(.,'Load more')]]
```

and before click the button scroll down.. so your code should looks like:

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/whatever/')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Load more')]]").click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: It's work, but when i tried to looping it, why it's not work ?? Can u help me ??

I was tried like this :
'''
while True:
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
'''

I put it after click button load more.

Comment: you have to count the total number of post after each scroll. when the counter is stabilized, you can break the while loop because you will have all the posts

Comment: I did, i get the total of the post. i tried to looping by the total of the post. I use it for show total of the post. 
'''
while True : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='_s53mj']/span[@‌​class='_bkw5z']").te‌​xt.replace(',','') '''

And i tried to looping by it but still error.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not error, but the looping always lopping from the top again, even though all data is already get, "while" still looping.